# How to create a training set of images for Neural Networking

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, neural-network

I am trying to implement a basic Neural Network in OpenCV. I've searched online and there are many different tutorials on it, but I can't find anything that describes how to make my own training set. Everywhere I go uses a premade training set of letters, numbers, or faces. I was wondering if there was any tutorials online that I could follow as to how to create my own training set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't give thorough directions, but one thing to note is that your training set should include both positive and negative examples of whatever features you're trying to teach your neural network. A friend of mine made a 'lizard-detection' image recognizer, but only trained it on pictures that actually had lizards. Sure enough, it could find a lizard in anything one showed it afterward.

Comment: doesn't depend on what you want your Neural Network to do? e.g. face recognition, human detection or whatever object detection

Comment: I'm looking for logo detection for the most part. I can find many tutorials online on face, human, and object (motion?), but I've been able to find nothing but Thesis papers that focus heavy on mathematical formulas or MATLAB references.

Comment: Do you have a scope of which logos you are going to detect? Or generally you want to detect all logo-like patches out of an image? Chosen of dataset heavily depends on your task, because you will need to introduce a lot of constraint in order to make your problem solvable. In other words, you need to define your problem precisely first, 'logo detection' is not a problem definition at all, it is too vague.

Comment: I do have a scope of the logos I wish to detect. Logos like Nike, Apple, Sprint, Target, etc. An example would be a general commercial for a restaurant. If I take the commercial and save it out to 1 second images and run the software I would like to find all logos displayed. Of course I would first scout the commercial to see what gets shown, but after the initial scout I would like any similar commercials to be able to have the logos detected.

Comment: Then probably what you can do is to find some of this kind of commercial first, and use a certain amount of images (the frames you extract from the video which has logos displayed) as your positive training example and the frames which doesn't contain logos as you negative training example. Try to find similar videos, because no algorithm works well in wild, you have to make your data consistent in someway

Answer (score 0):

I would use the logos you mentioned and use it on some sample data. You can get the Logos from the respective websites. 
Then you take all the false positives and use it as negative examples for your algorithm. And do the same thing for a different sample scene.
Detecting the logos in a video scene (or stills) might be to complicated for the first few iterations - with something easier like screenshots of websites you can work out the quirks of the technique before you jump to actual video footage.